# Comparing numbers with while loop. Python 3.8.3

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, integer

I am currently new to Python and trying to construct a program that takes two integers and outputs whether they are larger, smaller than each other or both equal. I also want to add a while loop which asks for 2 more sets of integers each time, otherwise if the user types "quit" the program ends. Only issue is, I think my casting is off as when I type quit, it actually compares that. So if I typed quit twice it would state they're equal which is true rather than stop the program.

```
onenumber = int(input("Please enter your first number to compare:"))

twonumber = int(input("Please enter your second number to compare:"))


if onenumber > twonumber:
    print (onenumber, "is the biggest!")
                            
elif twonumber > onenumber:
    print (twonumber, "is the biggest!")

else:
    print ("Both are equal!")


while onenumber != "quit":

    onenumber = input("Please enter your first number to compare, or type quit:")
    twonumber = input("Please enter your second number to compare:")    


    if onenumber > twonumber:
        print (onenumber, "is the biggest!")                           
    elif twonumber > onenumber:
        print (twonumber, "is the biggest!")
    else:
        print ("Both are equal!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your program does exactly what it should do. But think about it, your condition is stating: As long as onenumber is not "quit" execute all commands inside the while loop. So if your onenumber variable is "quit" it will still perform the comparison ONE TIME more before it ends the program. But after that your program will stop. But obviously this won't happen because an exception will occur. You can verify it with below code:

```
number1 = "proceed"
while number1 != 'quit':
      number1 = str(input("declare number1"))
      number2 = str(input("declare number2"))

      try:
         if int(number1) > int(number2):
            print("number1 is is bigger than number2")
         elif int(number1) < int(number2):
            print("number2 is bigger than number1")
         else:
            print("both numbers are equal")
      except:
            pass
```

One solution for example without Exception handling would be the following:

```
number1 = "proceed"
while number1 != 'quit':
      number1 = str(input("declare number1"))
      number2 = str(input("declare number2"))


      if number1 != 'quit':
          if int(number1) > int(number2):
              print("number1 is is bigger than number2")
          elif int(number1) < int(number2):
              print("number2 is bigger than number1")
          else:
              print("both numbers are equal")
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code slightly to begin in the while loop. Ideally, you want as few lines of code as you can and as you had two repeated lines I removed them.

Now that both number variables are not cast as int we can use the in-built string function `.isdigit()` which returns a True or False if the variable is a digit. This helps us out by ensuring there won't be an error when comparing them.

Happy to answer any questions you have!

```
while True:
    number_one = input("Please enter your first number to compare or type 'quit':")
    number_two = input("Please enter your second number to compare:")

    if number_one.isdigit() and number_two.isdigit():
        number_one = int(number_one)
        number_two = int(number_two)

        if number_one > number_two:
            print(number_one, "is the biggest!")
        elif number_two > number_one:
            print(number_two, "is the biggest!")
        else:
            print("Both are equal!")
    elif number_one == "quit":
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Please enter a number or type 'quit'!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.

https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html

```
number_1 = input("Please enter your first number to compare or type 'quit':")
number_2 = input("Please enter your second number to compare:")

try:
    smaller = int(number_1) < int(number_2)
    same = int(number_1) is int(number_2)
    if smaller:
        print(number_1, "is the smaller")
    else:
        print(number_2, "is the biggest")
    if same:
       print("Both are equal")

except ValueError:
    if number_1 == "quit"
       print("Thanks for playing!")
```